# TYPO3 9.5: update only typo3/cms-* packages with composer does not work

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-9.x

With earlier TYPO3 versions, a TYPO3 update via composer was easy:

```
composer update typo3/cms --with-dependencies
```

After the subtree split and with TYPO3 9.5 the update should be done like this according to the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/MigrateToComposer/BestPractices.html#update-packages):

```
composer update "typo3/cms-*" --with-dependencies
```

Unfortunately this does not work:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
```

Same applies for this (I'm using zsh so the wildcard needs to be escaped):

```
composer update typo3/cms-\* --with-dependencies
```

But there is definitely stuff to update:

```
composer update --dry-run
```

has this result:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 5 installs, 39 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating helhum/typo3-console-plugin (2.0.4) to helhum/typo3-console-plugin (v2.0.5)
  - Updating symfony/process (v4.1.7) to symfony/process (v4.2.1)
  - Installing symfony/contracts (v1.0.2)
  - Updating symfony/console (v4.1.7) to symfony/console (v4.2.1)
  - Updating symfony/intl (v4.1.7) to symfony/intl (v4.2.1)
  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (2.0.5)
  - Updating guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.4.2) to guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-core (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-core (v9.5.2)
  - Updating symfony/yaml (v4.1.7) to symfony/yaml (v4.2.1)
  - Updating symfony/finder (v4.1.7) to symfony/finder (v4.2.1)
  - Updating typo3/cms-recordlist (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-recordlist (v9.5.2)
  - Updating symfony/routing (v4.1.7) to symfony/routing (v4.2.1)
  - Installing symfony/var-exporter (v4.2.1)
  - Updating symfony/cache (v4.1.7) to symfony/cache (v4.2.1)
  - Updating symfony/expression-language (v4.1.7) to symfony/expression-language (v4.2.1)
  - Updating psr/http-server-middleware (1.0.0) to psr/http-server-middleware (1.0.1)
  - Updating doctrine/persistence (v1.0.1) to doctrine/persistence (v1.1.0)
  - Updating doctrine/common (v2.9.0) to doctrine/common (v2.10.0)
  - Updating typo3/cms-extbase (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-extbase (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-fluid (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-fluid (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-install (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-install (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-frontend (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-frontend (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-filelist (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-filelist (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-extensionmanager (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-extensionmanager (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-backend (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-backend (v9.5.2)
  - Updating doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5) to doctrine/instantiator (1.1.0)
  - Updating typo3/cms-belog (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-belog (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-scheduler (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-scheduler (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-adminpanel (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-adminpanel (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-tstemplate (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-tstemplate (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-sys-note (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-sys-note (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-setup (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-setup (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-recycler (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-recycler (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-reports (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-reports (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-opendocs (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-opendocs (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-lowlevel (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-lowlevel (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-info (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-info (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-beuser (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-beuser (v9.5.2)
  - Updating typo3/cms-seo (v9.5.1) to typo3/cms-seo (v9.5.2)
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v4.2.1)
  - Installing symfony/config (v4.2.1)
  - Updating helhum/config-loader (v0.11.0) to helhum/config-loader (v0.11.1)
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/service-contracts-implementation ()
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/translation-contracts-implementation ()
```

My `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "path", "url": "packages/*/" },
        { "type": "git", "url": "https://github.com/peterkraume/cbgooglemaps.git" },
        { "type": "composer", "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/" }
    ],
    "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
    "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.2"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "helhum/typo3-console": "^5.0",
        "typo3/cms-belog": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-beuser": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-info": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-info-pagetsconfig": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-lowlevel": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-opendocs": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-reports": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-recycler": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-setup": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^9.5",
        "typo3/cms-wizard-crpages": "^9.5",
        "kws/kws-theme-zmg": "@dev",
        "typo3-console/composer-auto-commands": "^0.2.0",
        "helhum/typo3-secure-web": "^0.2.7",
        "friendsoftypo3/cms-func": "^9.0",
        "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^9.5",
        "yoast-seo-for-typo3/yoast_seo": "^4.0",
        "brinkert/cbgooglemaps": "dev-jquery",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6"
    },
    "extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
            "web-dir": "public",
            "root-dir": "private"
        },
        "helhum/typo3-console": {
            "install-extension-dummy": "0"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Currently running `composer update typo3/cms-* --with-dependencies` which works fine on my system and updates the typo3/cms packages. So basically: that should work ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it's a known bug in composer. https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7261

I'll investigate and come back.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `composer why-not typo3/cms-core:9.5.2` to get more informations

Comment: And now `composer why-not doctrine/instantiator:1.1` ?

Comment: `typo3/cms-core  v9.5.1  requires  doctrine/instantiator (~1.0.4)`

Comment: I had a similar problem yesterday, i don't where it comes from... I ended up doing `composer require typo3/cms-core:9.5.2`. I don't remember if that solved the `composer update typo3/cms-* --with-dependencies`, or if i finally had to do the "full" `composer update`.
I'm sure there some version conflict with a package we required, but i didn't investigate further, and your composer trace is not really giving better informations than the one i had so... Sorry ^^

Answer (score 0):

I had this some problem. Please run `composer update --with-dependencies`. That works for me.

Comment: This will update everything at once (including third party extensions). You may not want that.